# Running a query using date from a form MS Access

Tags: date, ms-access

How do I run a query using a value from a textbox from a form I have? I know that there is another post here at Stackoverflow dealing with this issue but I found it to be insufficient for my needs.

I formated my textbox into Medium Date format with its default value being =Date(). However, when I pick up a date and open my report I get this error:

*Runtime error 3071: Expression Too Complex*

My *where* clause is this

```
WHERE 
(
     (AllInfo.DateOpened >= CDate([Forms]![Main Form]![WindowPrintOptions]![CustomizedReport]!txtDateOpenedFrom.Value))
)
```

and I am sure it is this code piece that is throwing the problem since when I take it out of the query the error message simply disappears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 (AllInfo.DateOpened >= DateValue([Forms]![Main Form]![WindowPrintOptions].[Form]!txtDateOpenedFrom))
```

)

Comment: With respect, I would have thrown this in a comment, and if it answered OP's question then throw it in an answer. Not trying to bash at all.

Comment: Well, I thought of just editing the answer if needed.

Comment: Then you may have to specify [Forms]![Main Form]![WindowPrintOptions].[Form]!txtDateOpenedFrom as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

I got the problem. It was the "AllInfo" alias. It wasn't applicable at that escope inside the query. By changing the proper things, it was enough to write:

```
[Forms]![Main Form]![WindowPrintOptions]![CustomizedReport]!txtDateOpenedFrom.Value
```

Issue solved. Thank you all!